# Load MVC View out of frame after redirection from an IFrame

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an IFrame in ASP.Net MVC View as:

```
 <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
     <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="@TempData["ThirdPartyUrl"]"></iframe>
 </div>
```

The third party website that loads into my IFrame makes a callback to action method after the required operations are performed in IFrame. Below is the action method in my controller that is being called back:

```
    public IActionResult DSReturn(string @event, string Id)
    {
        ViewData["results"] = $"Event: {@event}. ID: {Id}";
        return View();
    }
```

The issue is when I return View from above action method, it loads it again into the IFrame. I don't want that. I want it to be rendered like a normal View and not in an IFrame. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use client side scripts to redirect user to another location . After operations , you can try below code sample :

```
ContentResult result = new ContentResult();
result.Content= string.Format("<script >window.parent.location.href = '{0}';</script>", "YourURL");
result.ContentType = "text/html";
return result;
```

Comment: I was updating some old code that used ```return Content(myHtmlWithJsParentSnippet) ``` and replacing it with a ContentResult was the answer